# Usage example to generate and use ASTs using Eclipse CDT in a stand alone application

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt, abstract-syntax-tree

I want to implement error checking rules for lint styled static analysis of simple codes (single function, about 30-100 lines) in c, cpp, java and python. The main requirement for solving this is being able to generate ASTs.

I observed that the Eclipse IDE does a lot of static analysis, AST generation and processing using the plugins CDT, JDT, DLTK. I found that JDT could be used in standalone applications not requiring Eclipse to generate ASTs. However I wasn't able to find a working demo for a standalone implementation using CDT.

Is it possible to use them without having Eclipse or the editor modules running? Any suggestions on their usage/implementation to generate and process ASTs?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do single java/C file ASTs generation using jdt.core/cdt.core. If you want to get some information on semantic level, you have to do it in Eclipse plugin environment(Actually you can replace or remove some dependences with JavaPlugin or CPlugin to skip this restriction). I am not sure if you just need single file generation or a project level generation.